# Para ejecutar en php a SQL server 2008r2 ¿Que esta mal?

Tags: php, sql, server, odbc, mssql

Tengo la siguiente conexión:

Trato de ejecutar el siguiente Script pero no entiendo por que no da resultado:

```
    $query1 = $conn->prepare('SELECT UserUID FROM SQLserver2008.dbo.Tablas WHERE email = ? ');
    $query1->bindParam(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query1->execute();
    if(odbc_num_rows($query1)>0)
        {
            die("<center><h2><font color='red'>El Correo</font> <font color=#EEEA0B'>$email</font><font color='red'> NO esta Disponible</font></h2></center>");
        }
```

Me indica el Siguiente Error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Web_2\Info\ar_.php on line 176
```

La variable $email si carga le monte un simple echo y da true e imprime ejemplo MIEMAIL@midominio.com

Comment: por eso mismo es que estoy confundido justo estoy cambiando a la siguiente:

Comment: $conn  = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=127.0.0.1;Database=$database", $sqlUser, $sqlPass);

Comment: Y si conecta pero no entiendo por que el $conn

Comment: El error *`Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object`* ocurre porque el objeto que usas para invocar a `prepare`, (que en este caso es `$conn`) no es un objeto. Eso ocurre casi seguro porque la conexión no está funcionando por algún motivo, revisa las credenciales que estás usando y el DSN de conexión. Pon la conexión en un bloque try ... catch para capturar los errores y depurar el código con más facilidad. Además, si vas a usar PDO no mezcles con funciones de obdc como `odbc_num_rows` pues PDO tiene sus métodos propios.

Comment: si de hecho todas las credenciales fueron revisadas y ajustadas estuve leyendo que no se recomiendan juntar PDO y ODBC

Comment: Ok, pues si quieres depurar tu código pon la conexión en un bloque try ... catch, captura las excepciones y agregalo en la pregunta. Ahí te dirá por qué la conexión no está funcionando.